# How do I print out values from a select field with multiple values

Tags: entities, theming

Currently I have a select field with multiple string values in a custom node. I'm trying to print them out without any html markup.

Currently I am declaring my variable like this:

```
$categories = $content['field_category'];
```

And I'm trying to print it like this:

```
foreach ($categories['und'] as $item) {
    echo $item['value'];
}
```

But nothing gets printed out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you inspected `$item` with `dpm()` or similar stuff?

Comment: is this in a menu_hook() ? if so i don't think it will work you need to provide the callback with renderable html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making a custom loop like this and it works fine (Also added a custom if statement to change html output based on single or multiple categories in the field.

```
<?php 
    $categoryCount = count($field_category);
    if ($categoryCount != 1):
?>
    <p><strong>Categories:</strong>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><strong>Category:</strong>
<?php
    endif;
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $categoryCount) {
        if ($i != 0) {
            $html .= ', ';
        }
        $html .= $field_category[$i]['value'];
        $i++;
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```